# Add Literal Percent Sign (%) to my calculation inside raw query Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, concatenation

I get an error when I add a percentage symbol in the query:

> Exception Type:IndexError
>   Exception Value:tuple index out of range.

**views.py**

```
class groupdatagercekzamanliveriListView(ListAPIView):
query2 = gercekzamanlıveri.objects.raw("""SELECT 1 as id,
CONCAT(ROUND((SUM(net_uretim_miktari)/SUM(teorik_uretim_miktari)::float*100)),'%') as tee, FROM tee_gercekzamanlıveri
INNER JOIN tee_isyerleri ON tee_gercekzamanlıveri.isyeri_id= tee_isyerleri.id
INNER JOIN tee_malzemeler ON tee_gercekzamanlıveri.malzeme_id= tee_malzemeler.id
INNER JOIN tee_isyerimalzemebilgileri ON tee_isyerimalzemebilgileri.isyeri_id= tee_gercekzamanlıveri.isyeri_id 
AND tee_isyerimalzemebilgileri .malzeme_id = tee_gercekzamanlıveri.malzeme_id) as a GROUP BY isyeri_id""")

    queryset = query2
    serializer_class = groupdatagercekzamanlıveriserializer
```

**serializer.py**

```
class groupdatagercekzamanlıveriserializer(serializers.Serializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    tee = serializers.CharField()
```

When I use `"a"` as string for `"%"` no problem:

```
CONCAT(ROUND((SUM(net_uretim_miktari)/SUM(teorik_uretim_miktari)::float*100)),'a') as tee
```

**Result:** `"tee": 80a`

Comment: It should be a good idea to not use Raw SQL but Django ORM instead.

Comment: @Essex It should be good but I put some of it in order to make the query understandable. I used the RAW query because the query is very comprehensive.

Comment: Raw queries are totally fine as long as you know what you are doing (no dynamic values) or you are going beyond the ORM's capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) (GIYF first hit for `django sql "%"` - at least for me) you have to double it to have the character recognized as a literal, e.g.:

```sql
--
CONCAT(
  ROUND(
    (SUM(net_uretim_miktari) / SUM(teorik_uretim_miktari)::float * 100)
  ),
  '%%'
) as tee, FROM tee_gercekzamanlıveri
--
```